# How to make the PHP parser detect/read the HTML tags in the string?

Tags: php, string, html-parsing, substr

I have the following `PHP` code in which I want to extract a `sub-string`, *without losing the `HTML` tags in it.*

1. Although I want to keep the `HTML` tags in the string, the *`PHP`
   parser does not seem to read or detect the `HTML` tags* - the output
   of the program follows the code.
2. Secondly `'` seem to be replaced by `â€™`.
3. Thirdly, a minor side-question: Is there a way to store a string in
   a variable which contains both single and double quotes *when I can
   not escape the quotes*, like we can have *triple-`'`'s in python*?

**Please guide me about why both the problems are occurring and what can I do about them?**

```
<?php

$haystack = '<div class="qtext"><p>^^^^^When children experience emotional upset or trauma, their problems are sometimes made worse by well-meaning adults who either don’t notice their distress or insist that they express themselves through an adult medium: verbal language. Play therapy, on the other hand, recognizes that imaginative play is the mode of expression most comfortable and natural to children and focuses on helping them express their emotions. A form of psychodynamic treatment, play therapy takes for granted the fact that, once aided in expression, children are able to resolve their anxieties themselves.</p>
<p>The equipment of play therapy is simple and familiar. Dolls, play dishes, soldiers, stuffed animals, and sandboxes all have their place in the play therapy room. The job of the therapist, however, is a bit more challenging, because he or she must refrain from guiding the child in a particular direction or asking pointed questions. The therapist’s task is partly to observe the child’s play and recognize the child’s emotions and help bring them to expression. The second, very important, task is for the therapist to accept the child unconditionally.</p>
<p>A well-known example of successful play therapy is documented in Dr. Virginia Axline’s book Dibs in Search of Self. Dibs is an emotionally disturbed 5-year-old whose teachers fear he may have brain damage. In his play therapy sessions with Dr. Axline, however, a different picture emerges. Dibs’ play with a dollhouse and several dolls reveals that he feels cut off from his family and that he is angry with them for locking him in his room. This theme is repeated in play with animals in the room’s sandbox; he frees them from captivity again and again. During the sessions, Dr. Axline is careful not to express preference for any of Dibs’ activities, and most of her comments are simply reflecting back to him what he has just said. Additionally, through her choices to help him express his anger rather than offering him comfort in it, Dr. Axline fosters in Dibs a sense of emotional independence. At the end of the case study, Dibs has emerged as a content, intelligent, compassionate child.^^^^^</p>
<p>According to the passage, which of the following is a reason that play therapists help disturbed children express their emotions?</p></div><div class="ablock"><div class="prompt">Select one:</div>';

$start= strpos( $haystack, '^^^^^' ); //Find the position of the first occurance of vvvvv

$end= strrpos( $haystack, '^^^^^' ) ; //Find the position of the last occurance of vvvvv

$length= strlen($haystack);

$haystack_substring= substr( $haystack, ($start+5), ($end-$start-5) ); //end is the desired length of the returned substring. Since end is our substring of interest plus 5 v's, so we are doing -5 to passed the desired length of our substring

$haystack_substring .= '</p>';

echo $haystack_substring;
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
When children experience emotional upset or trauma, their problems are sometimes made worse by well-meaning adults who either donâ€™t notice their distress or insist that they express themselves through an adult medium: verbal language. Play therapy, on the other hand, recognizes that imaginative play is the mode of expression most comfortable and natural to children and focuses on helping them express their emotions. A form of psychodynamic treatment, play therapy takes for granted the fact that, once aided in expression, children are able to resolve their anxieties themselves.
The equipment of play therapy is simple and familiar. Dolls, play dishes, soldiers, stuffed animals, and sandboxes all have their place in the play therapy room. The job of the therapist, however, is a bit more challenging, because he or she must refrain from guiding the child in a particular direction or asking pointed questions. The therapistâ€™s task is partly to observe the childâ€™s play and recognize the childâ€™s emotions and help bring them to expression. The second, very important, task is for the therapist to accept the child unconditionally.

A well-known example of successful play therapy is documented in Dr. Virginia Axlineâ€™s book Dibs in Search of Self. Dibs is an emotionally disturbed 5-year-old whose teachers fear he may have brain damage. In his play therapy sessions with Dr. Axline, however, a different picture emerges. Dibsâ€™ play with a dollhouse and several dolls reveals that he feels cut off from his family and that he is angry with them for locking him in his room. This theme is repeated in play with animals in the roomâ€™s sandbox; he frees them from captivity again and again. During the sessions, Dr. Axline is careful not to express preference for any of Dibsâ€™ activities, and most of her comments are simply reflecting back to him what he has just said. Additionally, through her choices to help him express his anger rather than offering him comfort in it, Dr. Axline fosters in Dibs a sense of emotional independence. At the end of the case study, Dibs has emerged as a content, intelligent, compassionate child.
```

Comment: So you don't want to lose the tags in your initial string, but do you want HTML tags to be returned after you've got the text between you two `^^^^^`s?

Comment: @Jonathon Yess, exactly I want them returned as well. I just want them to be treated as simple characters here, like all other characters.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a copy of your input string, stripping out HTML tags using `strip_tags`, something like `$cpy = strip_tags($haystack);` and work from there

Comment: @Jonathon But I do not want to strip-out the HTML tags. I want to keep them there.

Comment: They will stay put in your original `$haystack` but they won't appear in `$cpy`. Is this not what you want? I'm a little confused otherwise

Comment: If you want to return HTML in your string doing what you're already doing by finding the start and end positions and returning the text inbetween should work

Comment: Just a thought.. the output of your program, are you viewing it in your browser or view-source? If it's the former, then the HTML tags will be interpreted by the browser and won't appear, try viewing the source to see a more raw output

Comment: @Jonathon Oh that is the culprit- viewing it in the browser. I just right clicked it and clicked `View Source` and I can see the HTML tags as desired. So I can be assured that my string actually contains those tags, but are being interpreted and hidden by the browser when it renders the output?

Comment: YEah that's right. If you're simply echoing out HTML tags the browser will interpret them as such. You could use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` to encode them so that they display as you would like without having to view source

Comment: I'll just to use `htmlentities`. I did not know about this function. Thank you very much. I'll be grateful if you can give some tips on the other two question if you have time, thank you for the answer.

Comment: The second issue seems to be an encoding issue. You should use the `header` function to tell the browser which encoding to use (`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`) or you can do it with a HTML meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`